# Recursive Quicksort in MIPS Assembly language

Tags: assembly, mips, quicksort

Trying to change the following java code into MIPS asm code. All the code i can find online is using the asm language designed for intel chips and not MIPS where they push the arguments onto the stack and not safe registers values.

```
void quicksort( int[] array, int p, int r) {
  if( p < r) {
    int q = partition( array, p, r);
    quicksort( array, p, q - 1);
    quicksort( array, q + 1, r);
  }
}

int partition( int[] array, int p, int r) {
  int pivot = array[ r];
  int i = p -1;
  for( int j = p, j < r; j++) {
    if( array[ j] <= pivot) {
      i = i + 1;
      swap( array, i, j);
    }
  }
  swap( array, i + 1, r);
  return( i + 1);
}

void swap( int[] array, int i, int j) {
  int temp = array[ i];
  array[ i] = array[ j];
  array[ j] = temp;
}
```

The following swap function was provided:

```
swap:
  addi  $sp, $sp,  -28    # Push the stack pointer down to hold seven values
  sw    $ra, 0 ($sp)      # Store the return address and s registers on the stack
  sw    $s0, 4 ($sp)
  sw    $s1, 8 ($sp)
  sw    $s2, 12($sp)
  sw    $s3, 16($sp)
  sw    $s4, 20($sp)
  sw    $s5, 24($sp)
  # Done with protecting registers. Now for the real work:
  sll   $s0, $a1, 2       # from * 4 into $s0
  sll   $s1, $a2, 2       # to * 4 into $s1
  add   $s2, $a0, $s0     # Address of array[from] into $s2
  add   $s3, $a0, $s1     # Address of array[ to] int9 $s3
  lw    $s4, 0($s2)       # Value of array[from] into $s4
  lw    $s5, 0($s3)       # Value of array[to] into $s5
  sw    $s4, 0($s3)       # Value from $s4 into array[to]
  sw    $s5, 0($s2)       # Value from $s5 into array[from]
  # Done with the work. No return value.
  lw    $ra, 0 ($sp)      # Restore the $ra and $s registers from the stack
  lw    $s0, 4 ($sp)
  lw    $s1, 8 ($sp)
  lw    $s2, 12($sp)
  lw    $s3, 16($sp)
  lw    $s4, 20($sp)
  lw    $s5, 24($sp)
  addi  $sp, $sp, 28      # Pop the stack pointer
  jr    $ra
```

Comment: That's a horrible `swap` function. Anyway, since you are supposedly "trying" ... show what you tried. Alternatively, use a compiler.

Comment: i know it is but this is what my professor provided. So far i am trying to follow his model doing partition but it's not going so well.

Comment: This is a Q&A website, yet there's no question in your post.

Comment: Start writing partition. From the sample `swap` function you see how to index into an array. That gives you `int pivot = array[r];`. You presumably know how to do subtraction and assignment. So next is the comparison...

Comment: When you google, use searches that include MIPS, like `mips array index`, `mips loop over array`, etc., maybe including `site:stackoverflow.com`. Otherwise yes, you'll get lots of results for x86, it gets talked about a lot on the internet.  (And often with 16-bit x86 code, not x86-64 where the calling conventions pass args in registers.  Not that it would help you at all, there are much more serious differences in trying to port x86-64 asm to MIPS when you don't know assembly language in general or x86-64 *or* MIPS in particular.)